# Modifying Array Contents using Splice

Tags: perl

I'm trying to work on a script which inserts a '1' at a particular array location using splice function, prints it and later inserts a '0' at the same location. The logic i have so far is :

```
my @array = (0) x 4096;
for ($j=0;$j<3;$j++) {
splice ( @array, $array[$j],1,1);
print "$j---$array[$j]\n";
splice ( @array, $array[$j],1,0 );
}
```

With this logic, the output I'm getting is :
    0---1
    1---0
    2---0

To be more precise, the output I was expecting out of this logic is :
    0---1
    1---1
    2---1

Am I using the splice function correctly here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need `splice` to do what you want.  Just a simple assignment is needed:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @array = (0) x 4096;
for (my $j = 0 ; $j < 3 ; $j++ ) {
    $array[$j] = 1;
    print "$j---$array[$j]\n";
    $array[$j] = 0;
}

__END__

0---1
1---1
2---1
```

Refer to:

```
perldoc -f splice
```

Answer (score 1):

`splice` wants an index not an element:

```
splice ( @array, $j,1,1);
```

in your case you are passing `0` (the element value) as the index so it inserts an element at the beginning. But replacing a single element with a single element is better done with simple assignment.